# BitTorrent daemon with IPv6 web interface?

Tags: linux, bittorrent

I'm looking for a BitTorrent daemon (for Debian) that

- has a web interface which
- can be accessed via IPv6.

[Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/) and [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) come to mind, but both of them seem to lack IPv6 support in the webinterface; see the corresponding [transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/2236) and [deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/1130) tickets.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an IPv6 capable frontend webserver (e.g. Nginx or Apache) to proxy requests to a torrent client listening locally.